# Create bean and call non-setter method

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-bean, elasticsearch-java-api

How can I create the following code into a Client bean in spring.xml so that I can inject Client(Object) into my Code ? I am configuring this bean to get data from elastic search.

```
Client client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.168.0.198",9300));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Spring FactoryBean that allows you to expose a Client bean and is easy to configure as a bean in Spring application context. For example

```
public class ClientFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Client>{

   private String ipAddress;

   private int port;

   public Class<?> getObjectType(){
       return Client.class;
   }

   public boolean isSingleton(){
      return true;
   }

   public void setPort(int port){
      this.port = port;
   }

   public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress){
      this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
   }

   public Client getObject(){
      return new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(ipAddress,port));
   }
}
```

Then in your application context file

```
<bean id="client" class="some.package.ClientFactoryBean">
   <property name="ipAddress" value="192.168.0.198"/>
   <propert name="port" value="9300"/>
</bean>
```

You can then inject the client bean as usually. NB. Its type will be Client not ClientFactoryBean as Spring will detect that its a factory bean and it will manage the result of the getObject call